# Azure AD Application Required Permissions list does not include all APIs

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory, required

I have created an application to use the Office 365 Exchange Online (Microsoft.Exchange) API. I set successfully set up permissions as described here [MS Integrating Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications) on an existing development Azure Account. See APIs available on original account. 
[image: Original Permission APIs]

However, now I want to set up a similar app in a new Azure account so I can have a different visible domain for the permission sign up process. However, on this new account the Exchange Online API is not visible to select as a required permission.

This account only exists as a place to register the App so it doesn't itself have any users or need any licenses but do I have to have a license associated with that account just to be allowed to add a particular API to the required permissions? The documentation doesn't mention anything about this that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

> do I have to have a license associated with that account just to be
> allowed to add a particular API to the required permissions?

Yes, you're right. **You have to have a Office 365 Exchange Online license for your Tenant.**

**Why:**

These APIs are exsiting in the AAD  as service principal (Enterprise Applications). If you don't buy Exchange Online license, it won't occurs in the Enterprise Applications in your tenant. Once you buy the license, it will be automatically added to the Enterprise applications, meanwhile you can use its API via AAD.

This makes sense because if you don't have the license, you cannot use the product and you cannot use its API neither.

> The documentation doesn't mention anything about this that I can see.

Yeah, the documentation maynot mention this and it should be noticed in the documentation. You can sign in the documenation webiste via a github account and give a feeback to the documenation Team:

[image]

Hope this helps!